# Attaching USB speaker killed laptop but later it worked again. Can fuses reset by waiting or removing battery?

Tags: usb, laptop, hardware-failure, power, speakers

Trying a USB speaker on my laptop caused it to power off and not power back on. I thought it blew a fuse or a chip and would need to be repaired.

Some people who are not computer techs gave me random advice:

- Leave it a while and it should just turn back on.
- Disconnect the battery and reconnect it.

I've had computers for forty years and these suggestions made me skeptical but didn't sound totally implausible. Maybe there were self-resetting fuses in modern laptops or some kind of safety circuit commonly employed in removable batteries and I just hadn't heard of them before.

After half an hour I unclipped the battery, clipped it back on and was pleasantly surprised that it did power up and works fine.

Are either or both of the fixes actually things that modern laptop designs in fact do?

The laptop is an HP ProBook 430 G2. I tried to Google whether this model has such features but couldn't find anything. Maybe they have specific names I don't know.

Comment: Power surge on the USB overloaded a resettable (thermal) fuse perhaps. After a while the fuse would cool back down and "reset" and allow power to flow again...

Comment: Its going to be really hard to answer this question given that the problem has gone away, so other than doing guesses is all we can do. This bascially turns this question into an off-topic one given you cannot actually validate the solution. I'm voting to close this for that very reason.

Comment: @LPChip: Why is guessing essential? Can no person know the safety features of this HP model? Which topic is not allowed? USB speakers or power problems both seem like applicable topics for the site.

Comment: The problem is that we can suggest answers, but given that you cannot say for sure if it solves the problem, a questions like this does not belong on a Q and A kind of site.

Comment: It's also possible Windows had issues with the driver. Windows 10/ UEFI has made old troubleshooting methods difficult. Try plugging in the speakers while booted to UEFI and see what happens, check the device drivers if it only happens in Windows... Overall, this question is a bit short on hard data so it's hard to answer any more definitively than some hypothetical situations.

Comment: @LPChip: I've reworded the question. I want to know which of the two features modern laptops have and which this specific model has. I'm not looking for anyone to get this speaker working on the laptop. I want to learn about laptop power safety features.

Comment: @AustinTFrench: I don't care about the speaker. I care about the power safety features of the laptop I thought I'd broken. I didn't get a BSOD or anything. Just suddenly the power was gone. Is that something UEFI sometimes does? I actually removed details because people thought I was asking how to get the speakers working. I'm asking whether my laptop is designed to survive such an episode and how.